# Failure delivering result ResultInfo - obtaining image from gallery

Tags: android, photo-gallery, onactivityresult

This question has been asked many times, however none seem to answer my issue.  I have an app that allows the user to a. take a pic and upload or b. select from gallery.

I have been testing this on three devices samsung s4/s3 and LG nexus 4.  It works fine and haven't been able to crash it.

However, I have received notification through crashlytics that it has crashed on a motorola moto g.

Here is my code:

```
private void launchImageGallery(){
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gallery Launched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String imagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
            rotationMatrix.postRotate(90.0f);
            Bitmap bitty = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(imagePath, 300, 300);
            Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitty, 0, 0, bitty.getWidth(), bitty.getHeight(), rotationMatrix, true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            fromGallery = true;
            BitmapDrawable bmp = null;
            Log.i("GALLERY BITMAP SIZE: ", String.valueOf((sizeOfBitmap(bitty))/1000)+ " kb");

//            normal portrait: 0
//            normal landscape: 90
//            upside-down portrait: 180
//            upside-down landscape: 270
//            image not found: -1

            if(getOrientation(getActivity(), selectedImageUri)!=90){
                bmp = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitty);
                //galleryImage.setImageBitmap(bitty);
                bitty.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            }else{
                bmp = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),rotatedImage);
                //galleryImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
                rotatedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            }

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>14){
                galleryImage.setBackground(bmp);
            }else{
                galleryImage.setBackgroundDrawable(bmp);
            }

            snapPic.setText(getString(R.string.rate_this_beer));
            image = stream.toByteArray();
            beerDetailsAnimate();
        }
    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // just some safety built in
        if( uri == null ) {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }
        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();
    }
```

The logs I get from the crash are:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=132071, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/poyCKb42_JLYFjZbndpgDzRBr7gEdfX8hNc4Dy6utJs=s0-d flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.purpledecks.bottomsup/com.purpledecks.bottomsup.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.purpledecks.bottomsup.fragments.Beer_Camera_fragment.onActivityResult(Beer_Camera_fragment.java:1077)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:167)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

So unfortunately I'm unable to test on this device so i'm not sure where it's going wrong, can anyone see the issue?

Comment: Which line in the code you gave is Beer_Camera_fragment.java, line 1077?  That's where the NullPointerException is occurring, right?

Comment: a simple schoolboy error.  on line 1077 i have a boolean to state if it's taken from the gallery or not, it was globally initialised and reinitialised if this is called, however, depending on the path the user uses this could result in a NPE...thanks for your help..you helped me see the woods from the trees!